# Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge camera glitch

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, samsung

My friend has the Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge for about 2 months and her front facing camera is turning all her pictures a red negative effect on it. I will show an example [image: Nothing is added other than it being the selfie setting] the other camera settings work perfectly fine, it's just the front facing camera with the selfie function. The video front facing camera works fine also. She is going to take it back to the shop but she said her old phone, a Note 4, had a similar problem. Occasionally when she is using her front facing camera, it'd go to the red negative effect. I hope I can get a reasonable answer on why this is happening other than her supernatural belief of ghosts. I'll include another picture that is using her back camera.[image: the only difference is the fact it is taken from the back camera]

Comment: If video is working fine camera should work fine. It must be the modified settings. PS - There are no  ghosts.

Comment: She is glad to hear that it should not be a ghost problem! Though, I couldn't really see any settings in the camera she may have accidentally changed. I'll look at her settings again to see if I missed anything. Thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: Just a few days ago her phones 'Selfie' portion of the front facing camera started working though. Though once in awhile it will randomly go back to the weird red inverted look. She claims to not have touched anything at all. I went through her camera setting and messed with them all and I have not found anything what's so ever that supposedly made her pictures turn into this.

Answer (score -1):

I too getting the same problem.I restarted the phone then it's works again properly.